# Двумерный казатель на массивы

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Есть текст задания:

Допустим, что нам нужно сохранить 100 целых чисел так, чтобы иметь к ним легкий доступ. Допустим, что при этом у нас есть проблема: память нашего компьютера так фрагментирована, что может хранить массив, наибольшее количество элементов в котором равно десяти (такие проблемы действительно появляются, хотя обычно это происходит с объектами, занимающими большое количество памяти). Вы можете решить эту проблему, определив 10 разных массивов по 10 элементов в каждом и массив из 10 указателей на эти массивы. Массивы будут иметь имена а0, a1, а2 и т. д. Адрес каждого массива будет сохранен в массиве указателей типа int*, который называется ар. Вы сможете получить доступ к отдельному целому используя выражение ap[j] [к], где j является номером элемента массива указателей, а к — номером элемента в массиве, на который этот указатель указывает. Это похоже на двумерный массив, но в действительности является группой одномерных массивов.

Заполните группу массивов тестовыми данными (скажем, номерами 0, 10, 20 и т.

д.), а затем выведите их, чтобы убедиться, что все работает правильно.

и сам код

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 10;

int main() {
    int arr0[SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9, 10},
    arr1[SIZE] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80,90, 10},
    arr2[SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9 , 10},
    arr3[SIZE] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80,90, 10},
    arr4[SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9 , 10},
    arr5[SIZE] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80,90, 10},
    arr6[SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9 , 10},
    arr7[SIZE] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80,90, 10},
    arr8[SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9 , 10},
    arr9[SIZE] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80,90, 10};

    int *ap[SIZE][SIZE] = {{arr0}, {arr1}, {arr2}, {arr3}, {arr4}, {arr5}, {arr6}, {arr7}, {arr8}, {arr9}};

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
            cout << ap[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout <<endl;
    }
}
```

Не пойму как сделать как реализовать двумерный указатель.

Comment: `int **p = ap;`

Comment: `int* ap[SIZE] = {arr0, ...};`

Comment: ```int* ap[SIZE] = {arr0, ...};``` пробовал так, выводило за место значений 0

Comment: решил по итогу очень криво
```int **ap = new int* [SIZE];

    ap[0] = arr0;
    ap[1] = arr1;
    ap[2] = arr2;
    ap[3] = arr3;
    ap[4] = arr4;
    ap[5] = arr5;
    ap[6] = arr6;
    ap[7] = arr7;
    ap[8] = arr8;
    ap[9] = arr9;
```

Comment: способ, который предложил wololo работает корректно.

Comment: `выводило за место значений 0` [Звучит неправдоподобно](https://rextester.com/TRYN12897).

Answer (score 0):

решил по итогу очень криво:

```
int **ap = new int* [SIZE];
ap[0] = arr0;
ap[1] = arr1;
ap[2] = arr2;
ap[3] = arr3;
ap[4] = arr4;
ap[5] = arr5;
ap[6] = arr6;
ap[7] = arr7;
ap[8] = arr8;
ap[9] = arr9;
```